# How to start LightGallery in fullscreen mode?

Tags: jquery, fullscreen, lightgallery

I use the great LightGallery js module: https://github.com/sachinchoolur/lightGallery
https://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightGallery/

How can I start LightGallery in fullscreen mode?
Fullscreen mode can be activated by clicking the icon in the toolbar, but how to start a slideshow in full-screen mode?

Answer (score 4):

I've found the following answer posted by plugin's author (sachi77n) in the comments section of the official page (https://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightGallery/).

I'll post it here for anyone that tries to achieve this functionality.

---

You can trigger the fullscreen function on lightGallery's `onAfterOpen.lg` event.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $lg = $('#lightgallery');
    $lg.lightGallery();
    $lg.on('onAfterOpen.lg', function(){
        $lg.data('lightGallery').modules.fullscreen.requestFullscreen();
    });
});
```

Demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xgEBZq.